# What does this Haskell error - parse error on input ‘=’ mean?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I'm running the following code to demonstrate pattern matching from a book:

```
lucky :: (Num a) => a -> String
lucky 7 = "LUCKY NUMBER SEVEN!"
lucky x = "Sorry, you're out of luck, pal!"
```

[image]

This gives the following error:

```
parse error on input ‘=’
Perhaps you need a 'let' in a 'do' block?
e.g. 'let x = 5' instead of 'x = 5'
```

I can see in other similar situations errors like this are caused because the syntax of Haskell change to make older books invalid.

Has the syntax of Haskell changed to make this code invalid since the book was written?

My question is: **What does this Haskell error - parse error on input ‘=’ mean?**

Comment: I think this has nothing to do with the function you show. This works fine on my machine.

Comment: Haskell is indentation-sensitive. Check the code before `lucky` function.

Comment: Don't think this is error is related to `lucky`. Instead I got "Could not deduce (Eq a) arising from the literal ‘7’". Adding the required constraint fixed it, though.

Comment: Looks like `lucky`'s definition is the very first in `Main.hs`. Have you forgotten the `module Mood where` declaration?

Comment: @NormenMüller Using `module ...` is optional. It should work anyway.

Comment: The error looks very weird: there's no `=` in that line. Maybe your IDE is misconfigured somehow? E.g. it is trying to call `ghci` instead of `ghc` or is feeding the wrong code to the compiler? If you manually load your code in GHCi it should work just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Eq` used to be a constraint on `Num`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.4.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Num):

```
class (Eq a, Show a) => Num a where
```

[This is no longer the case](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Num):

```
class Num a where
```

As a result, use of equality (including pattern matching, which is implicitly equality) must carry an `Eq` constraint.

As for your specific error message, I suspect this is a bad IDE integration more than anything, but the change-up of intended behaviors in GHC will cause confusion for other's trying to diagnose and answer your problem if it isn't explicitly taken into account.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the issue shown was garbage whitespace copied from the PDF that the IDE failed to filter out. 
(Thanks everyone for your assistance).